# Trying to make a class for persistent variables, not sure how I should make the setter for the class

Tags: python, class, getter-setter

```
class PersistenVars:
    
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            # Saved variables as a list [start, end, index]
            self.content = eval(file.read())
            
        self.start = self.content[0]
        self.end   = self.content[1]
        self.index = self.content[2]
```

Whenever I update the value of `self.start`, `self.end` or `self.index` I also want to update the file and `self.content` (with the new values).

I first tried using a property decorator for each attribute but I'm just writing the same thing over and over again for something that does the same purpose.

```
class PersistenVars:
    
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            # Saved variables as a list
            self.content = eval(file.read())
            
        self._start = self.content[0]
        self._end   = self.content[1]
        self._index = self.content[2]
        
    @property
    def start(self):
        return self._start
    
    @start.setter
    def start(self, value):
        self.content[0] = self._start = value
        with open(self.filename, 'w') as file:
            file.write(repr(self.content))


# And the same thing for the end, index
```

What's the most pythonic way to go on about this?

Comment: Be very sure nobody else can edit the backing store before `eval`ing its contents.

Comment: You are basically trying to reimplement the `pickle` module from scratch.

Comment: (Actually, `shelve` might be more appropriate. `pickle` serializes values; `shelve` uses `pickle` to implement a mapping whose changes can be automatically written to disk on assignment.)